# Copied data to LVM-Thin pool by mistake

Tags: filesystems, lvm, mount, data-recovery

I'm here today because of a big mistake that I have made.

---

I **created an LVM-Thin data pool** (and not on a LVM-Thin LV) on my Proxmox server  and (don't ask why) **ran a mkfs.ext4** on the pool **then mounted it** on my local node. After that **I copied a bunch of data** on it and stopped my system:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/pve-data
mount /dev/mapper/pve-data /mnt/data/
cp -r Temp/ /mnt/data/
```

The next time I **created a VM** on this pool from the Proxmox GUI, and you guessed it, **found out what I had done** too late.

I tried to **mount the pool again** (even if that shouldn't be possible) **without any success** as you can guess:

`lvm thin mount: *: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/*, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

*Tried `mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/pve-data /mnt/data` too.*

---

I searched if I **could restore the FS** on it with a `fsck` or something but didn't do it by **fear of making my data inaccesible** forever.

Finally I **tried to use PhotoRec** on my disks, but because of the time it takes to run I stopped it.

I wanted to know if there was **something else to do** (with `fsck` for exemple) before letting PhotoRec **run for days** on my disks?

Could you help me?

Comment: Please provide the exact commands you run on the system.

Comment: @shodanshok I updated my post with the commands.

Comment: How it is ever possible to access the volume for creating file system and mounting after it was converted to the thin pool data LV?

Comment: Don’t know myself why it was allowed by the system. It was a case of figure not taken into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trashed your data-containing volume, so you are not going to see its data again. You must restore from backup.

Comment: I think so too. I will have to try working with PhotoRec. If I find something I will write it here. If not I will mark your answer as the correct one. Thanks.